# Export import in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have class Panels and class Panel in my ui.
I want to avoid multiple statements such as `import Panel.. and import Panels ...` every time I decide to use them.

Instead, I want to re-export Panel from Panels once, and in my app just say something like `import * from 'Panels.js'` causing both Panel and Panels appear in the scope of my App.

Is this possible? Good tutorial on the subject? thanks.

Comment: You can add the `javascript` tag to the question, it's relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import several things from the same module like so:

```
import { Thing1 , Thing2 } from "module-name";
```

Or import everything like so:

```
import * as everything from "module-name";
```

For all other variations see: https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: it is important to note that the first option uses ES6 feature destructuring

Answer (score 2):

You can use `import * as Panels from 'Panels';`

Inside your code you should use `Panels.Panel` and `Panels.Panels`

> Don't forget that you need to `export` both in order to `import` them